Generating chart problem for LST Estimation
This is the error message I get:

Error generating chart: Collection.filter, argument 'collection':
Invalid type. Expected type: FeatureCollection. Actual type:
Image<[LST]>.

Here is the code I made:https://code.earthengine.google.com/f51be97645d7ce1116d2246f85c25ce5
var startDate = '2015-01-01';
var endDate = '2015-12-31';

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
// Scale and offset values for optical bands
var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
 
// Scale and offset values for thermal bands
var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
 
// Add scaled bands to the original image
return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
.addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

// Function to Mask Clouds and Cloud Shadows in Landsat 8 Imagery

function cloudMask(image) {
  // Define cloud shadow and cloud bitmasks (Bits 3 and 5)
  var cloudShadowBitmask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudBitmask = (1 << 5);

  // Select the Quality Assessment (QA) band for pixel quality information
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');

  // Create a binary mask to identify clear conditions (both cloud and cloud shadow bits set to 0)
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitmask).eq(0)
                .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitmask).eq(0));

  // Update the original image, masking out cloud and cloud shadow-affected pixels
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
// Import and preprocess Landsat 8 imagery
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
              .filterBounds(table)
              .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
              .map(applyScaleFactors)
              .map(cloudMask)
              .median()
              .clip(table);
print(image, 'colection');

// Define visualization parameters for True Color imagery (bands 4, 3, and 2)
var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.15,
};

// Add the processed image to the map with the specified visualization
Map.addLayer(image, visualization, 'True Color 432');

// Calculate Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');

// Define NDVI Visualization Parameters
var ndviPalette = {
min: -1,
max: 1,
palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']
};

Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviPalette, 'NDVI Kabul');

// select thermal band 10(with brithness temperature), no calcualtion
var thermal = image.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.00341802).add(149);
var b10Params = {min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// Calculate the minimum NDVI value within the AOI
var ndviMin = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer   : ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry  : table,
  scale     : 30,
  maxPixels : 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndviMin, 'min');

// Calculate the maximum NDVI value within the AOI
var ndviMax = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
  reducer   : ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry  : table,
  scale     : 30,
  maxPixels : 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(ndviMax, 'max');



// Fraction of Vegetation (FV) Calculation
// Formula: ((NDVI - NDVI_min) / (NDVI_max - NDVI_min))^2

// Calculate the Fraction of Vegetation (FV) using the NDVI values within the specified range.
// NDVI_min represents the minimum NDVI value, and NDVI_max represents the maximum NDVI value
var fv = ((ndvi.subtract(ndviMin)).divide(ndviMax.subtract(ndviMin)))
          .pow(ee.Number(2))
          .rename('FV');
        
Map.addLayer(fv);

// Emissivity Calculation
// Formula: 0.004 * FV + 0.986

// Calculate Land Surface Emissivity (EM) using the Fraction of Vegetation (FV).
// The 0.004 coefficient represents the emissivity variation due to vegetation,
// and the 0.986 represents the base emissivity for other surfaces.

var em = fv.multiply(ee.Number(0.004)).add(ee.Number(0.986)).rename('EM');

// Select Thermal Band (Band 10) and Rename It
var imageVisparam3 = {min:0.9865619146722164, max:0.989699971371314};
Map.addLayer(em, imageVisparam3, 'EM');

// Select Thermal Band (Band 10) and Rename It
var thermal = image.select('ST_B10').rename('thermal');

// Now, lets calculate the land surface temperature (LST)

// Formula: (TB / (1 + (λ * (TB / 1.438)) * ln(em))) - 273.15
var lst = thermal.expression(
  '(TB / (1 + (0.00115 * (TB / 1.438)) * log(em))) - 273.15', {
    'TB': thermal.select('thermal'), // Select the thermal band (TB)
    'em': em // Assign emissivity (em)
  }).rename('LST');

// Add the LST Layer to the Map with Custom Visualization Parameters
Map.addLayer(lst, {
  min: 18.47, // Minimum LST value
  max: 42.86, // Maximum LST value
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ]}, 'Land Surface Temperature 2015');
  

// Define the time period
var startDate = '2015-01-01';
var endDate = '2015-12-31';

// Load MODIS LST data
var modisLST = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .mean()
  .multiply(0.02)  // Scale factor for MODIS LST
  .subtract(273.15);  // Convert to Celsius



// Compare with Landsat8 LST
var comparison = ee.Image.cat(lst, modisLST).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: table,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e7
});

print('Comparison between Landsat and MODIS LST:', comparison);

// Calculate difference
var difference = lst.subtract(modisLST).rename('Difference');
Map.addLayer(difference, {min: -10, max: 10, palette: ['red', 'white', 'blue']}, 'Difference');

// Sample points across the area of interest (AOI)
var samplePoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(table, 50);

// Add LST values to the sample points
var trainingSample = lst.sampleRegions({
  collection: samplePoints,
  properties: ['lst'],
  scale: 30
});

// Load the uploaded CSV table
// Load the uploaded CSV table
var table = table2;

// Print to check the data
print(table);

// // Create a scatter plot
// var scatterPlot = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(trainingSample, 'LST')
//   .setChartType('ScatterChart')
//   .setOptions({
//     title: 'LST Comparison: True vs. Classified',
//     hAxis: { title: 'True LST (°C)' },
//     vAxis: { title: 'Classified LST (°C)' },
//     pointSize: 2
//   });

// print(scatterPlot);

// Create a scatter plot.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(lst, 'Landsat_LST', ['modisLST'])
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Comparison of Landsat 8 and MODIS LST',
    hAxis: {title: 'Landsat 8 LST (°C)'},
    vAxis: {title: 'MODIS LST (°C)'},
    pointSize: 3,
    trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} }
  });

print(chart);


The question lack necessary details and research effort. It's not clear what is your end goal beside making the error message disappear! The error message is because you provided image: lst inside ui.Chart.feature.byFeature which takes featurecollection as input. you also specified property names that don't exist
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-chart-feature-byfeature
